# Interger truncate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a very large DB that takes time to process request due to the amount of data held, I am trying to to improve my python methods and need to to convert this number 1543282500000 that is ()  to  readable human date by attempting to truncate number to 15432825 and then to date:

I have tried:

```
for i in range(2, len(df)):
    df.at[i, 1110] = pd.to_datetime((df.at[i, 0]), unit='s')
    df.at[i, 1110] = pd.to_datetime(int(df.at[i, 0]), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S', errors='ignore')
```

But it returns

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'
```

and the second statement in the loop returns:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is unsliceable
```

Comment: What happens if you change `unit='s'` to `unit='ns'`?

Comment: or perhaps `unit='ms'`.

Comment: Thank you John, I saw the options in Pandas manual but, since the first options did not work, I thought of truncate would do the trick; but look just one letter!!! thank you for your help.